# Client Server array change detection best practices or design pattern

Tags: java, javascript, c#, design-patterns, client-server

Which technique are you using when you want to detect changes on the server side in array sent by client?

E.g. very simple scenario, we have an array of `Persons`, client side gets it from server, and changes it in three ways

- **Adds** new `Person`
- **Updates** existing `Person` (changes name)
- **Deletes** `Person`

and sends array to server, which is responsible for storing it in `Database`, but first it must detect incoming changes and save it.
Currently I do detect incoming changes with this approach:

- Items with no `Id` field are considered as **Added**
- Items which are not present on the client side, but only on server side, are considered to be **Deleted**, (I detect it comparing `Id` fields)
- Items which are present on both side (again detected with comparing `Id` fields) are considered **Updates**

First two are OK as far as there's small number of elements(**Deleted** object detection would be inefficient in array with e.g. 10k elements and more).

Another approach about I'm thinking but haven't tried it is to **Add extra field** on **ViewModels** sent by client to server, which may have three values **Added, Deleted, Updated**.

What's your favorite solution? Suggest me best practices, Or if there's a dedicated design pattern to this.